# Interpreting complex narratives

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

I've been struggling with understanding the usage of past tenses in complex narratives such as this one:

> Once, Aunt Petunia, tired of Harry coming back from the barbers looking as though he hadn’t
> been at all, had taken a pair of kitchen scissors and cut his hair so short he was almost bald except for
> his bangs, which she left “to hide that horrible scar.” Dudley had laughed himself silly at Harry, who
> spent a sleepless night imagining school the next day, where he was already laughed at for his baggy
> clothes and taped glasses. Next morning, however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had
> been before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off. He had been given a week in his cupboard for this, even
> though he had tried to explain that he couldn’t explain how it had grown back so quickly.

I think I have a general idea what these tenses (past perfect simple / past simple) are used for and how to combine them together yet whenever I try to read a book in English I eventually run into something along these lines and end up becoming frustrated and confused, not being able to understand why they've been used this way.

From what I understand, the main purpose of employing the past perfect tense in a narrative like this is to try and convey some sequence of events. And another, perhaps equally as important, is to convey the meaning of present perfect-type sentences in the past.

And the latter seems to be apparent here, where the fragment in bold seems not to be in reference to any other past event.

> , tired of Harry coming back from the barbers looking as though **he hadn’t been at all**,

And so, I assume in the sense of event sequencing the part above can simply be omitted and therefore we're left with:

> Once, Aunt Petunia [...] had taken a pair of kitchen scissors and cut his hair so short he was almost bald except for his bangs, which she left “to hide that horrible scar.”

And assuming I'm right about my analysis, so far this would somewhat make sense to me.

But then, the following sentence starts with:

> **Dudley had laughed** himself silly at Harry, **who spent** a sleepless night imagining school the next day, where **he was already** laughed at for his baggy clothes and taped glasses.

And here's where I don't know what's happening anymore.

- First of all, I don't understand if I should interpret this part separately or did the frame of reference change with the narrative and now this part is supposed to be referring to the last event that took place which is the **cutting of his hair** or **him being bald** or even **her hiding that scar**
- Assuming it is, why would it then start with past perfect? In the context of the narrative it seems as though **Dudley laughed after Harry's hair had already been cut** but clearly that's not what's written so I'm confused here.
- Actually, the way I'd put it would be something like this: "Dudley **laughed** himself silly at Harry, **who'd spent** a sleepless night imagining school the next day, where **he'd already been** laughed at for his baggy clothes and taped glasses."

As for the last part:

> Next morning, however, he had gotten up to find his hair exactly as it had been before Aunt Petunia had sheared it off. He had been given a week in his cupboard for this, even though he had tried to explain that he couldn’t explain how it had grown back so quickly.

I'm utterly clueless and have no idea why would all of it be put in the past perfect.

I'd greatly appreciate any help with interpreting this particular narrative in a way that it's actually meant to be interpreted, as well as any tips that would be useful whilst trying to interpret similar things that I might come across in the future as it's something that's ever-present in pretty much every story book. Feel free to challenge my assumptions and tell me if I made any mistakes anywhere along the way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Harry used to come back from the barber's looking as though he had not been to the barber's (i.e. the barber hadn't cut much off his hair). This must be an American edition, as it uses _bangs_ and _gotten_!

Comment: Harry is remembering that, on one occasion when this happened, his aunt had cut his hair very short and Dudley had laughed at him because he looked silly. I suspect that the author didn't use **had spent a sleepless night** simply to avoid repeating **had**; the reader can understand that this also happened after the haircut and the laughter. The next paragraph goes back to the past perfect because it's still describing Harry's memories of the incident.